# Strange short path name on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, filenames

In my home directory on Windows, I have plenty of `dotfiles` and `dotfolders` that get created by software, and that I create myself for consistency.  I've never really thought much about it, except when I try to create them in the explorer interface and am reminded I can't do that, which is annoying, but whatever.

I was looking at my `PATH` environmental variable and realized that one of these folders had been renamed strangely when converted to the Windows short name. 
 Most of the `dotfiles` and `dotfolders` look something like this (long name on right, short on left):

```
CACHE~1    .cache
CPAN~1     .cpan
GOOGLE~1   .googlecl
```

etc.

However, one folder (my `go` path folder) was renamed like this:

```
GO288D~1   .go
```

The only thing I can figure is that it has something to do with it being a two digit `dotfolder` name; is that why? What is actually happening?  What does `288D` mean, and why does Windows place it there?

Comment: By any chance, does the `go` path folder contain a trailing space?  If so, a legacy/short name would still be created.  Here is a good reference that I have found to be handy:  [How Windows Generates 8.3 File Names from Long File Names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142982/how-windows-generates-8.3-file-names-from-long-file-names)

Comment: By default 8:3 file name creation is on but can be disabled: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/121007/how-to-disable-8.3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions

If you create, as an example, a directory, shorter in length, E.g. *mkdir .go*, then you'll end up with something like: GO288D~1, when you run *dir /X*.  The hex characters to pad out the name, i.e. 288D, according to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename are derived from an "undocumented hash of the filename".

Comment: @EMK - Excellent reference, and I'm pretty sure it's the answer, so you should consider submitting your comment as an answer, quoting the full paragraph which discusses the "undocumented hash".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 8:3 file name creation enabled ([can be disabled but not without risk](https://support.microsoft.com/help/121007/how-to-disable-8.3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions)), if you create, for example, a directory shorter in length than 8:3 as you have, E.g.

```
mkdir .go
```

...then you'll end up with a 8:3 file name of: GO288D~1:

```
>dir /X | find ".go"
23/02/2017  16:48    <DIR>          GO288D~1     .go
```

The additional hex characters to pad out the name, i.e. 288D, according to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename are derived from an "undocumented hash of the filename"

> Beginning with Windows 2000, if at least 4 files or folders already
>   exist with the same initial 6 characters in their short names, the
>   stripped LFN is instead truncated to the first 2 letters of the
>   basename (or 1 if the basename has only 1 letter), followed by 4
>   hexadecimal digits derived from an undocumented hash of the filename,
>   followed by a tilde, followed by a single digit, followed by a period
>   ., followed by the first 3 characters of the extension.

Comment: To expand on this, here's a blog post which reverse-engineers how the hash function is generated, at least on Windows x64. https://tomgalvin.uk/blog/gen/2015/06/09/filenames/